# Python unittest assertions truncate messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

- When I compared two lists in python3 in unittest, list1[0]==list2[0] equal. But in assertstatement it's show as differ like `AssertionError: Lists differ: ['vcp[174 chars]'`. Here may I know what are 174 chars, how it compares in assert statements?

```
- list1 = ['vcp', 'trpv1', 'tert', 'terf', 'steroid hormones', 'steroid', 'sorla', 'serpinc1', 'sar', 'saf', 'proteasome', 'prn', 'pka', 'pir', 'phenytoin', 'phenothiazines', 'phenobarbital', 'p gp', 'p97', 'p450', 'neurokinin 2 receptor', 'nadph', 'ml 1', 'mast', 'leukotrienes']
- list2 = ['vcp', 'trpv1', 'tert', 'terf', 'steroid hormones', 'steroid', 'sorla', 'serpinc1', 'sar', 'saf', 'proteasome', 'prn', 'pka', 'pir', 'phenytoin', 'phenothiazines', 'phenobarbital', 'p97', 'p450', 'p gp', 'neurokinin 2 receptor', 'nadph', 'ml 1', 'mast', 'leukotrienes']
(Pdb) self.assertListEqual(list1, list2)
*** AssertionError: Lists differ: ['vcp[174 chars]', 'p97', 'p450', 'p gp', 'neurokinin 2 recept[40 chars]nes'] != ['vcp[174 chars]', 'p gp', 'p97', 'p450', 'neurokinin 2 recept[40 chars]nes']

First differing element 17:
'p97'
'p gp'

  ['vcp',
   'trpv1',
   'tert',
   'terf',
   'steroid hormones',
   'steroid',
   'sorla',
   'serpinc1',
   'sar',
   'saf',
   'proteasome',
   'prn',
   'pka',
   'pir',
   'phenytoin',
   'phenothiazines',
   'phenobarbital',
+  'p gp',
   'p97',
   'p450',
-  'p gp',
   'neurokinin 2 receptor',
   'nadph',
   'ml 1',
   'mast',
   'leukotrienes']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`unittest.maxDiff`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unittest.html#//apple_ref/Attribute/unittest.TestCase.maxDiff) value to `None` to have the `unittest` library not limit the length of diffs it generates.

(On a side note, I'd suggest using [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) instead.)